# Need AES encryption in GNU radio

Tags: encryption, aes, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

[image: My Encryption Program]

I'm trying to make a simple program in GNU Radio to help understand (and test) the encryption blocks. I have attached a screenshot of my program. Basically, it takes a picture of a cat from a .png file and sends it to another.png file. I sent it three ways so as to see how it behaved. One way went straight from file to file, one went through only encryption, and one went through encryption and decryption. With the lower half of the program (the encryption and decryption) disabled, it works on the first route, but when I enable the lower half in an attempt to simultaneously do all 3 paths, the first path only sends the top half of the cat image, and the other two don't send any data to the files at all. The image of my program can be found in the link above this post. I'm new to this so my apologies if this was a bad post, but thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: um, why the two file sinks per output? They literally write the same thing, byte for byte.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I forgot those were there. I originally put them there to see if anything would go to a .txt file instead of a .png file. It was just a vain attempt and you're right that it had no effect on anything. Do you have any idea why it's behaving the way it is?

Comment: probably the file source signals "done" before anything happend in your decrypt. Did you test these blocks in isolation?

Comment: (by the way, this is GNU Radio 3.7; that's in legacy maintenance mode. If you're starting a new project, please use GNU Radio 3.8. It's cleaner, supports modern C++ and python3 instead of python2...)

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry for the late response but yes I have tested the blocks in isolation and they still don't ever let any data through. I don't have any idea what's causing this.

Comment: well if they don't work in isolation, then you should be debugging their source code. Since we don't know what you've wrote, we can't help you...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I didn't write them. They came from some library but I'm not sure which one because I didn't install them. Thank you for your help!